# Unable to add Custom DNS to GitLab Pages

Tags: gitlab, cname, gitlab-pages

I'm unable to add custom DNS to GitLab pages. I have done all the required changes by adding `A` and `CNAME` to my domain.

References : https://about.gitlab.com/2017/03/06/we-are-changing-the-ip-of-gitlab-pages-on-gitlab-com/

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_three.html

I also see a message by GitLab which talks about the custom DNS issue-
  https://about.gitlab.com/2018/02/05/gitlab-pages-custom-domain-validation/.
But I do not see an update on the issue.

Does anybody have an update on this issue?
Is there an alternative workaround for this issue?

**P.S** : If anybody is wondering why I'm not using GitHub pages, well... it's only for the reason that I can have private repos for my pages.